# How to individually add each letter of the alphabet into a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm trying to add each letter of the alphabet into a python dictionary, but I don't want to add it manually.

I have tried using `string.ascii_lowercase`, but it does not add each letter individually into the dictionary. Is there a way to add each letter in individually without doing it manually?

```
import string

dict = {'letter':string.ascii_lowercase, 'appearances':0}
print(dict['letter'], dict['appearances'])
```

I'm trying to get it to print out, `'a' 0, 'b' 0`, etc. However, instead, it is printing out `'abcdefg...z' 0`. Is there a way to enter then print out each letter individually followed by 0?

Comment: What's your expected result? A list of dictionaries `[{"letter": "a", "appearances": 0}, {"letter": "b", "appearances": 0}, ...]`? Or just `dict.fromkeys(string.ascii_lowercase, 0)`?

Comment: My expected result is like, each letter of the alphabet followed by a 0, each one on a different line.

Comment: `for letter in string.ascii_lowercase: print(letter, 0)`? [Edit] your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize your dictionary with dict comprehension:

```
import string

d = {k: 0 for k in string.ascii_lowercase}
for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Prints:

```
a 0
b 0
c 0
d 0
...and so on.
```

Dictionary `d` contains:

```
{'a': 0, 'b': 0, 'c': 0, 'd': 0, 'e': 0, 'f': 0, 'g': 0, 'h': 0, 'i': 0, 'j': 0, 'k': 0, 'l': 0, 'm': 0, 'n': 0, 'o': 0, 'p': 0, 'q': 0, 'r': 0, 's': 0, 't': 0, 'u': 0, 'v': 0, 'w': 0, 'x': 0, 'y': 0, 'z': 0}
```